# Number of CPUs for Celery and Nginx

Tags: nginx, celery, nginx-reverse-proxy

If I have 8 CPUs, how will it be divided between Nginx and Celery if Celery automatically creates number of processes equal to number of CPUs?
Same for Nginx.

Do I have to manually set this option in both Nginx and Celery?

Comment: For nginx you are looking for the [`worker_processes`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes) directive.

Comment: I know how to change above options. The question is how do they interact and do I really need to change them?

Comment: Why would Nginx processes interact with Celery processes (I automatically mean IPC here). Define what kind of interaction you mean?

Comment: I thought that when Nginx occupies the CPU, Celery doesn't have access to that CPU.